# Get Month from int value

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Can i get name of `month` in `JSLT` by giving an `int` value.
Like If i=1 than January and So no...

It is not working

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="M" dateStyle="long" value="${monthInt}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `<jsp:useBean>` as:

```
<jsp:useBean id="monthNames" class="java.text.DateFormatSymbols" />
<c:set value="${monthNames.months}" var="months" />
```

Now, I have initialized list of months using `<c:set>` corresponding to the index.
You could access it using `months` which is declared in `var`.

You could use it as `${months[0]}` it will give you `January`.

Hope it will work.!!

Answer (score 2):

JSTL expects a `Date` to be provided to the `fmt:formatDate` tag.  In the example an `int` is provided.  If you have extracted this `int` from a `Date` object, just pass that `Date` instead, no need for extracting the month value.

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="M" dateStyle="long" value="${someDate}" />
```

Comment: I have `int` value not `Date`

Comment: I understand, but jstl requires a date

Answer (score 1):

This won't work. The tag formats a `Date` object into a `String`, so the `value` needs to be a `Date`. You're giving it an `int`.

If you need a list of months then you might want to consider creating a list and putting it in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${monthInt}" dateStyle="long" pattern="M" var="monthDate"></fmt:parseDate> 
<fmt:formatDate value="${monthDate}" pattern="MMMM"></fmt:formatDate>
```